# Is there a way to mark all mail as read at the end of every day?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, automation

Is there a way to automatically mark all the emails in my Gmail inbox as read at the end of every day?

Even better, if it *didn't* mark the email in the 'Primary' tab read.

Note: I am looking for an *automatic* way to do this *at the end of the day*.

Comment: Do you know how to code? Google provides tools that should be able to do this pretty easily if you can code: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](http://mikecr.it/ramblings/marking-gmail-read-with-apps-script), I got a script and modified it:

1. Go to [script.google.com](https://script.google.com), and select 'Gmail' from the left hand side of the popup.
2. Delete all existing code, and paste this (the modified version):

> ```
> function markAllAsRead() {   
>   var threads = GmailApp.search('in:unread');   
>   GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads); 
> };
> ```

3. Save the file, and run it, making sure to allow access when it asks you.
4. Go to Resources > Current Project's Triggers and add a trigger to do it, for example every week.

Comment: Please note it is www.script.google.com not scripts! Otherwise v helpful tho

Comment: Thanks @h4xxr, edited! :)